# CSS background-image property

Tags: css, html

here is my html:

```
<div id="banner" style="background-image: url("img/banner.jpg")">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
#banner {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vw;
  background: url("/img/banner.jpg");
```

I want the banner.jpg to be the background of that div with full viewport fill... what to do?

Comment: What's the current result?

Comment: I belief it should work. try removing style attribute from div. and write this code for class instead of id.

Comment: height should be 100vh not vw, width should be 100vw. Will also need to add background-size: cover and adjust the positioning of the background-image if needed.

Comment: yep i deleted the <style> in my html, did the vh and background-size is set to auto... result is it a white expanse of where the background image should be.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS code:

```
    #banner{
    width: %100;
    }
```

Comment: tried... didnt work.

    #banner {
  width: %100;
  background: url("/img/banner.jpg");

Comment: Can you even see the photo on the browser as background image? If not use <img src="type the path of the image here">.

Comment: yep. i checked that. the banner.jpg showed on the site. what do you think my css should be on #banner?

thanks

Comment: The #banner above in @Raevenk 's answer seems to work. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried it on test HTML file and it worked. but on my project file, it doesnt. this is the CSS I'm using.

    .banner {
  background: url("img/banner.jpg") no-repeat;
  height:100vw; width:100%;
  display:block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

and for my html:
<div class="banner">  
  </div>

I'm stumped tbqh.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would achieve the effect https://jsfiddle.net/d5Lptwut/10/

```
<div id="banner">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
</div>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#banner {
  background: url('/img/banner.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```